# Redux dispatch causing component local state to reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using Redux with React. I'm using `this.state` (component local state) to save component specific variables. Problem is that my components state resets to initial state whenever I dispatch an action (fetch action) and Store updates (mounts).

1. Is this the correct behavior for my component? Should the component's state reset when it mounts a second time (re-render)?
2. If (1) is true, is there a way to preserve certain variable values in `this.state` when it receives new props from Redux store? I would prefer not to store all my components local states in Redux.

Comment: No it normally shouldn't but you probably have bad practices in your code, hard to say without any code posted

Comment: Thank you @DominicTobias, good to know. Knowin that made me look deeper into my code and it looks like it could be react-router-dom causing the components within <Switch><Route exact path="" component={ ()=><Login /> } /></Switch> components to mount on props update. Not sure why... troubleshooting continues. Many thanks!

Comment: In which lifecycle method are you initializing your state? It should be in the constructor

Comment: I'm defining it in the constructor.

class LoginForm_UsrPwd_Step1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { usernameInput: '', passwordInput: '' }
    }

Comment: Hm yes strange, that would normally cause a component update cycle, not a new mount!

Comment: Maybe using `highlight updates` in the react dev tools might help to see if more components react to that change then you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks @Markus ! 
Didn't know that feature existed. Looks like the react-route-dom <Route > component is causing the issue. It seems to unmount and then mount my Login component when I dispatch an action in Redux.

Comment: Eureka!!
I found the reason. I had implemented the react-router-dom Route component the wrong way. I was using the Router component function <Router component={()=><Login / >}/> which then would re-mount its child component.

Instead, I should have use the render function within the Router component. 

Using the constructor to instantiating the component state now works like a charm.

I'll do some more victory laps in the almost empty office (slightly embarrassed) and then crunch away :)
Thank you for your support guys! Truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason**:  I had implemented the react-router-dom Route component the wrong way. I was using the Router **component** function

```
<Router component={()=><Login / >}/>
```

which then would re-mount the child component.

**Solution**: Use the **render** function within the Router component.E.g.

```
<Router render={()=><Login / >}/>
```